# Loop through data in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to display data in a chart. and I have data passed from my controller as below.

```
0: {label: "500", backgroundColor: "rgb(102,205,170,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(102,205,170,0.5)", data: "13,49,2,2"}
1: {label: "1000", backgroundColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", data: "40,2,41,4"}
2: {label: "1500", backgroundColor: "rgb(112,128,144,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(112,128,144,0.5)", data: "3,41,0,8"}
3: {label: "2000", backgroundColor: "rgb(220,20,60,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(220,20,60,0.5)", data: "28,30,40,43"}
4: {label: "2500", backgroundColor: "rgb(240,230,140,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(240,230,140,0.5)", data: "0,6,20,14"}
5: {label: "3000", backgroundColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", data: "31,26,31,32"}
```

now I want to loop through the data so the result is like

```
label: '500',
backgroundColor: rgb(102,205,170,0.5),
borderColor: rgb(102,205,170,0.5),
data: [
    26,2,41,13
],
...
```

What I have tried is as follows

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataChart)) {
     console.log(key.borderColor);
}
```

here i have am only trying to display borderColor but it says `undefined'

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is `value.borderColor` instead of `key.borderColor`

Answer (score 1):

When using `Object.entries` and destructuring each iteration to `[key, value]`, `key` is the actual key of the current iteration: `0, 1, 2 ...` and `value` if the actual object.

Then if you want to get `borderColor` :

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataChart)) {
     console.log(value.borderColor); // borderColor is an attribut of value, not key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var entries = {
0: {label: "500", backgroundColor: "rgb(102,205,170,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(102,205,170,0.5)", data: "13,49,2,2"},
1: {label: "1000", backgroundColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", data: "40,2,41,4"},
2: {label: "1500", backgroundColor: "rgb(112,128,144,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(112,128,144,0.5)", data: "3,41,0,8"},
3: {label: "2000", backgroundColor: "rgb(220,20,60,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(220,20,60,0.5)", data: "28,30,40,43"},
4: {label: "2500", backgroundColor: "rgb(240,230,140,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(240,230,140,0.5)", data: "0,6,20,14"},
5: {label: "3000", backgroundColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", borderColor: "rgb(0,191,255,0.5)", data: "31,26,31,32"}
}

for (var prop in entries)
{
    console.log(entries[prop]["data"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the instructions `const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataChart)` you're creating 2 variables (`key` and `value`). Those 2 variables contains every single element of the array (`value`) and the index of the element into the array (`key`). So time by time, `key` is just a number.

Btw I suggest to use a different approach:

```js
dataChart.forEach(elementOfArray => {
    console.log(elementOfArray.borderColor);
});
```

The `forEach` is more used in js, it use the concept of callback. It will call the function you pass as param for every single element of the array by passing the array element as param.